Is the package xunicode still needed with XeLaTeX?
I searched all over and could not find a proper answer for this. If my document only uses OpenType fonts (e.g., NewCM10-Book, NewCMMono10-Book, NewCMMath-Book and Roboto), with fontspec and unicode-math, is xunicode still needed?
As far as I can see, xunicode is a "transition" package, but I am not very sure of what it does and if it is still needed.

no, do not use it anymore.

@UlrikeFischer Looks like the answer to me
